# Subject to permlink convertion in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, diacritics

I'm trying to convert user input, which is a subject for a blog entry into a permlink, which is used as URL and file system path.

I managed to do it using:

```
echo 'This is a used input, containing junk!!!! öäü' | tr -dc '[:alnum:] ' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -s ' ' '-' | sed -e 's/ö/oe/' | sed -e 's/ü/ue/' | sed -e 's/ä/ae/' | sed -e 's/ß/ss/'
```

Output: this-is-a-used-input-containing-junk-oau

The code absolutely works!

But is there a nicer way to do this without the need to pass the string through this much subcommands?

**Task to perform on the string**

- convert to lowercase
- replace space with "-"
- no multiple "-"
- no special characters, umlauts (covering German umlauts is sufficient, covering all would be a plus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're transliterating characters. `iconv` can handle this:

```
$ echo 'ö ä ü ß' | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT
oe ae ue ss
```

This requires your locale to be set to `de_DE.UTF-8` (or something similar) to get the results you expect (from your question & profile, I've made the assumption you're dealing with German text).

To set this for just the iconv command, use something like:

```
$ echo 'ö ä ü ß' | LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT
```

It's also possible you're not using UTF-8 but ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15; consider switching to UTF-8 if possible, or adjust the `-f` parameter accordingly.

Unfortunately, GNU `tr` (ie. Linux systems) is stuck in the 7-bit ASCII days(!), and doesn't support converting the case of anything other than a to z (it uses the "xor with 0x20 trick").

Since you are converting your string to 7-bit ascii anyway, we can use `tr` *after* `iconv` for it to work as expected:

```
echo 'ö ä ü ß' | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT | \
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

I don't see a problem with the other 2 `tr` invocations; they all do something different. Convert uppercase to lowercase, remove repeating characters, and remove whitespace.
Combining it in one "smart" command might look good now, but maybe not so good for the guy or gal who has to maintain it in 3 years time :-)

Putting it all together, and adding some line breaks, we end up with:

```
$ echo 'ö ä ü ß' | \
    iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT | \
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | \
    tr -dc '[:alnum:] ' | \
    tr -s ' ' '-'
```

Comment: + 1, though I actually think it *would* make sense to combine the `tr -dc '[:alnum:] ' | tr -s ' ' '-'` into a single command, because they're really doing one thing (replacing each non-alphanumeric sequence with a hyphen). One such command: `sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]]\{1,\}/-/g'`.

Comment: I've read about iconv in other places. However I didn't know that it converts not only the encoding/codepage, but also translates the content accordingly. This is awesome! I've used it now including the suggestion from ruakh. Works great! Thank you.

`echo "$input" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]]\{1,\}/-/g'`

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten `sed` some to:

```
echo 'This is a used input, containing junk!!!! öäü' | tr -dc '[:alnum:] ' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -s ' ' '-' | sed 's/ö/oe/;s/ü/ue/;s/ä/ae/;s/ß/ss/'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Let say you have the following line**

```
This is a used input, *%$^$^%$[]             containing junk!!!! öäü  ÄÜßÖ
```

**using sed command as follows:**

```
sed -r 's/[ ]+/-/g;s/[^[:alnum:]-]+//g;s/-+/-/g;y/üöäÄÜÖß/uoaauob/;s/.*/\l&/g'
```

**trying the above string with this command**

```
 echo 'This is a used input, *%$^$^%$[]             containing junk!!!! öäü  ÄÜßÖ' |sed -r 's/[ ]+/-/g;s/[^[:alnum:]-]+//g;s/-+/-/g;y/üöäÄÜÖß/uoaauob/;s/.*/\l&/g'
```

**results**

```
this-is-a-used-input-containing-junk-oau-aubo
```

Note: All upper case characters (including upper case umlauts) are lower case as requested.

Answer (score -1):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use utf8;
binmode $_, ":utf8" for qw/STDOUT STDIN STDERR/;
use Text::Iconv;
my $converter = Text::Iconv->new("UTF-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT");

while (my $line = <>) {
    $line = $converter->convert($line);
    $line = lc $line;
    $line =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;
    $line =~ s/\s/_/g;
    print $line;
}
```

#### USAGE:

```
echo 'This is a used input, containing JUNK!!!! öäü' | ./script.pl
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
this_is_a_used_input,_containing_junk_oeaeue
```

Comment: I was getting to it :-) ... You've expanded a few simple shell commands 15-fold to a full blown script; which I would consider far too complicated for this simple task ... Not only that, this script (badly) reinvents the transliteration of a few characters, which is much better handled by `iconv` or a similar tool/library (a mistake copied from the OP)... It's also not more readable than shell script example, IMHO, and required Perl knowledge to even guess what it guess (like `lc` meaning lowercase).

Comment: Added the use of ICONV in my POST

Comment: As much as I like perl. I don't think it makes much sense to mix up languages. So I stick with the bash + tools options. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote. I don't have the reputation yet to vote at all.