# How to format UTF8 to Subject Header the right way?

Tags: android, linux, bash, email

i am testing to send myself some emails with german umlauts like ä, ü, ö.
This is the command I use:

```
echo "ä ü ö" | mail -a "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" -s "test ä ü ö" test@example.com
```

But I get this on the standard Android Email Client:

```
test@example.com
test ?? ?? ??
ä ü ö
```

It works fine if I write myself an Email via Thunderbird or similar.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This could be useful, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27711356/5291015

Comment: I am not sure how to use this in my command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIME (`Content-Type:`) headers specifies encoding of email BODY.
[ BTW your MIME (content-type) headers are incomplete]

There is another encoding ([RFC-2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047)) for email headers (`Subject:`,`From:`,...).

Below please find link to answer with "perl oneliner" doing such conversion.
https://superuser.com/a/972248/209289

The script below should work if you use utf-8 based locales.
[ It seems to work with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` ]

```
#!/bin/sh
SUBJECT="test ä ü ö"
SUBJECT=`perl -MEncode -CA -e 'print Encode::encode("MIME-Q",$ARGV[0])' "$SUBJECT"`

/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- test@example.com <<END
Subject: $SUBJECT
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

ä ü ö
END
```